# Unexpected virtual function dispatch when using base class reference instead of pointer

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, undefined-behavior, object-lifetime, vptr

Let say I have a simple class hierarchy as follows with a common api:

```
#include <memory>

class Base {
    public:
        void api() {
            foo();
        }

    protected:
        virtual void foo() {
            std::cout << "Base" << std::endl;

        }
    };

    class FirstLevel : public Base {
    protected:
        virtual void foo() {
            std::cout << "FirstLevel" << std::endl;
        }
    };
```

when I use the base class pointer I get the correct dispatch as follow:

```
std::shared_ptr<Base> b = std::make_shared<Base>();
std::shared_ptr<Base> fl = std::make_shared<FirstLevel>();

b->api();
fl->api();
```

Which correctly prints :

```
Base
FirstLevel
```

However when I use the base class reference the behavior is unexpected:

```
Base &b_ref = *std::make_shared<Base>();
Base &fl_ref = *std::make_shared<FirstLevel>();

b_ref.api();
fl_ref.api();
```

which prints:

```
FirstLevel
FirstLevel
```

Why is the dispatch different when using references as opposed to pointers?

Comment: In the second case, the `std::shared_ptr` created by `make_shared()` cease to exist at the end of the expression, which also destroys the object they contain.    Both `b_ref` and `f1_ref` therefore are dangling references.   Using them then causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Peter You're repeating what was already said in two answers posted 10 minutes earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have undefined behaviour, because the references are dangling at the point you use them to call `api()`. The objects managed by the shared pointers cease to exist after the lines used to initialize `b_ref` and `fl_ref`.

You can fix it by having references to objects that are still alive:

```
auto b = std::make_shared<Base>();
auto fl = std::make_shared<FirstLevel>();

Base &b_ref = *b;
Base &fl_ref = *fl;
```

Comment: Do not use those references beyond the life of b and f1.
That's UB too.

Answer (score 2):

The return value of `std::make_shared` in the last example is not bound to an rvalue (`std::shared_ptr<...>&&`) or `const`-qualified lvalue reference (`const std::shared_ptr<...>&`), its lifetime is hence not extended. Instead, the return value of `std::shared_ptr::operator*` of a *temporary* instance is bound to the left hand side of the expression (`b_ref`,  `l_ref`), which results in undefined behavior.

If you want to access the virtual `api()` method through non-`const` lvalue references to `Base` and `FirstLevel`, you can fix this by

```
auto b = std::make_shared<Base>();
Base& b_ref = *b;

b_ref.api();
```

and similar for `FirstLevel`. Don't use `b_ref` after `b` goes out of scope, though. You can achieve lifetime extension by

```
auto&& b = std::make_shared<Base>();
Base& b_ref = *b;

b_ref.api();
```

though this is almost identical to the above.

Comment: I'm not sure these are candidates to lifetime extension.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yep, just realized that this was bogus :) Thanks.

Comment: Your opening paragraph still suggests there could be lifetime extension.

Comment: It is still a bit confusing, because the extension you refer to would be to `shared_ptr<T>` objects, but the references on the LHS are to `T`.

Comment: @juanchopanza True. Should be unambigious now.

Answer (score 0):

Making a smart pointer (or any owing object) a temporary is bad design.

That design issue causes bad lifetime management, specifically the destruction of an object which is still used. That causes undefined behavior; undefined behavior by definition isn't defined or even bounded by the standard (it can be bounded by other principles, tools, devices).

We can still try to understand how code with UB is translated in practice in many cases. The *specific behavior* you observe:

> which prints:
>
> ```
> FirstLevel
> FirstLevel
> ```

is certainly caused by interpreting the memory left by the destroyed object as if it was live object; because that memory was not reused at that time (due to chance, and any change to the program or the implementation may break that property), you see an object in the state it had during destruction.

In the destructor, the calls of virtual functions of the object being destructed always resolve to the overrider of the function in the class of the destructor: inside `Base::~Base`, the call to `foo()` resolves to `Base::foo()`; a compiler that uses vptrs and vtables (in practice, all compilers) makes sure the virtual calls are resolved that way by resetting the vptr to the vtable for `Base` at the beginning of the execution of the base class destructor.

So what you see is the vptr still pointing to the base class vtable.

Of course, a debugging implementation has the right to set the vptr to some other value at the end of the destructor of a base class to make sure that trying to call virtual functions on destroyed object fails in a clear and unambiguous way.